# Posting Data with Kimonolabs Webhook

Tags: post, kimono

I stuck at the problem, that if I want to post my Kimono Data via Webhook in my Database it gives me a JSON like this:

```
{ "name": "",..."results": {"collection1": [{ ...}]}
```

The problem is that these kind of JSON creates one single row in my database with one attribute results where all my data is stored. But actually I need the elements in the result collection in different rows to be able to work with them. I tryed to transform the data with the given feature in Kimonolabs but i doesn't think it's gonna work like this.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: I mean Ruby, Python...PHP. Not important. Good luck with  it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a little workaround. When you create a class for your Kimono data where you store the posts from the webhook, you can write a cloud code afterSave method. So if a new row in the Kimono class appears, the afterSafe method gets executed. Now you can split and modify your data and save it in a separate table. Works fine for me.

Comment: Are you using Parse.com? How did you create a webhook url for KimonoLabs.com? Would you be able to help out?

Comment: Sure... you have to go to Kimono> Use Data>Webhooks There you have to insert a custom string so that Kimono knows where to post the new data... The string should look like:   https://**your application ID***:javascript-key=****your javascript key***@api.parse.com/1/classes/your_class    of course without the stars... you get these keys on your dashboard>your App settings> Keys

Comment: Thanks for that! I will also try and link this to a function. It would probably be like this at the end: /1/functions/my_function_name. Thanks again.