# How to Create a Web Hook URL through Parse.com?

Tags: url, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, webhooks, kimono

I have a service (KimonoLabs.com) that I want to link with Parse.com. I need to provide a webhook URL that will push data to Parse.com. How can this be done in Parse.com?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to ask Tobias Dre how to do this.

Answer for webhook link:

https://**your application ID***:javascript-key=****your javascript key***@api.parse.com/1/classes/your_class

Credit: [Posting Data with Kimonolabs Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737073/posting-data-with-kimonolabs-webhook)